# React Native flex align components individually

Tags: javascript, react-native

https://snack.expo.io/ryBiTXJSf

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Button title="left" style={styles.button} />
          <Button title="center" style={styles.button} />
          <View style={styles.button} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.container2}>
          <View style={styles.buttonLeft}>
            <Button title="left" />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.buttonCenter}>
            <Button title="center" />
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    paddingTop: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  container2: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  button: {
    // flex: 1,
  },
  buttonLeft: {
    alignItems: 'left',
  },
  buttonCenter: {
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

I have 2 buttons on the same line. I want one button to be aligned to the left, another to the center.

How can I accomplish this? (share your snack link if you manage to get it working pls)

The above code shows 2 (failed) attempts at it.

Comment: We can't even be more than two at once on your problem ... What kind of code snippet is that ? And I got an error on my side, saying the the app stopped working. I don't even know what buttons you're talking about, I didn't see any. I'm flagging yoru question.

Comment: @trichetriche what's wrong with the code? I'm showing 2 different attempts at making the 2 buttons align. Try run it on iOS (use the embedded preview if you don't have iPhone, it's not working on Android for some reason.)

Comment: What's wrong is that they ask to subscribe to their website when more than 2 users aree using your code sample. And as I told you, I get an Android error saying your application crashed, so I've actually never seen it, because after reloading the page there was 2 other people on it.

Comment: @trichetriche copy the code above and run it locally. You are flagging my post because Expo snack's monetisation policy? Do you have suggestion for a better alternative than snack for React Native snippet testing?

Comment: I would have flagged it if there was no code, so that's pretty much the same in your case. And literally any online sandbox editor can do it. I just went on React's official website and **[found that](https://codepen.io/pen?&editors=0010)**, I'm pretty sure you could have done it too.

Comment: @trichetriche do you know what's the difference between ReactJS and React Native?

Comment: I guess react native is for phone applications since you used Snack. But isn't your issue is related to CSS ? Are React and React Native the same framework, only that React Native allows you to get access to phone functions ? Anyway, I flagged your question and I'm not the only one. I don't even had to justify myself, I did it out of courtesy. If I'd known you'd make a fuss about it, I would have not done it.

Comment: @trichetriche React Native's styling is not completely identical to web's css, I know how to do it with a web app. One would need knowledge of React Native specifically to help with this. I have removed the css tag to avoid further confusion.

Comment: You should take a look at my answer @Avery235

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a button on the left and one in the center, you need to create 3 boxes : left, center, right.

The right would be empty, the center would center elements, and the left would stay as "default".

I made a snippet to explain it just below, unfortunately I don't know React enough so I'll let you translate this into react to try.

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #ecf0f1;
  }
  
.left {
    align-items: left;
}
  
.center {
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.item {
  flex: 1 1 33%;
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item left"><button>Left button</button></div>
  <div class="item center"><button>Center button</button></div>
  <div class="item right"></div>
</div>
```

**EDIT** I think this would be

```
return (
  <View>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.left, styles.item}><Button title="left"/></View>
      <View style={styles.center, styles.item}><Button title="center"/></View>
      <View style={styles.right, styles.item}></View>
    </View>
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: '100%',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  left: {
    alignItems: 'left'
  },
  center: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  item {
    flex: '1 1 33%',
    width: '33%'
  }
});
```

Comment: My mistake was trying to apply style to `Button` instead of a `View` that wraps around it. `flex: 1` is sufficient to make the 3 views same width in React Native.

Comment: This should be runnable on your device now: https://snack.expo.io/BJyN7FerM

Comment: Flex 1 is enough, but it doesn't fix the width of your containers, meaning that the content will expand the div. So you should also fix the width at least, just to be sure!